# Remove strings from a list that contains numbers in python

Tags: python

Is there a short way to remove all strings in a list that contains numbers?

For example

```
my_list = [ 'hello' , 'hi', '4tim', '342' ]
```

would return

```
my_list = [ 'hello' , 'hi']
```

Comment: Well this changes the question entirely

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Without regex:

```
[x for x in my_list if not any(c.isdigit() for c in x)]
```

Comment: where do you find this misc useful functions like any()?

Comment: @thavan: http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html

Comment: How would you do this if you had a data frame?

Comment: could someone explain c.isdigit part?

Answer (score 7):

I find using [`isalpha()`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isalpha) the most elegant, but it will also remove items that contain other non-alphabetic characters:

> Return true if all characters in the string are alphabetic and there is at least one character, false otherwise. Alphabetic characters are those characters defined in the Unicode character database as “Letter”

```
my_list = [item for item in my_list if item.isalpha()]
```

Comment: He wants to remove strings with numbers, but special characters (spaces, punctuation,…) are probably allowed.

Comment: Except it won't work for punctuation

Comment: That's correct. I still thought I'd include it because it *will* work for many scenarios.

Comment: And written "old style", which works (IMHO) for readability in this case (and if run on 2.x) is, `filter(str.isalpha, my_list)`

Comment: That's not old style! I would do it that way

Comment: The problem with this is that it also removes characters åäö, but that is exactly what I want to do, remove all non characters

Comment: @user1506145 - then define it in your question please.

Comment: @user1506145 it will work just fine if you encode them in unicode, i.e. by using the `u` prefix as in `u'åääö'`. In Python 3, all strings are unicode and this is not an issue.

Answer (score 4):

I'd use a regex:

```
import re
my_list = [s for s in my_list if not re.search(r'\d',s)]
```

In terms of timing, using a regex is significantly faster on your sample data than the isdigit solution.  Admittedly, it's slower than `isalpha`, but the behavior is slightly different with punctuation, whitespace, etc.  Since the problem doesn't specify what should happen with those strings, it's not clear which is the best solution.

```
import re

my_list = [ 'hello' , 'hi', '4tim', '342' 'adn322' ]
def isalpha(mylist):
    return [item for item in mylist if item.isalpha()]

def fisalpha(mylist):
    return filter(str.isalpha,mylist)

def regex(mylist,myregex = re.compile(r'\d')):
    return [s for s in mylist if not myregex.search(s)]

def isdigit(mylist):
    return [x for x in mylist if not any(c.isdigit() for c in x)]

import timeit
for func in ('isalpha','fisalpha','regex','isdigit'):
    print func,timeit.timeit(func+'(my_list)','from __main__ import my_list,'+func)
```

Here are my results:

```
isalpha 1.80665302277
fisalpha 2.09064006805
regex 2.98224401474
isdigit 8.0824341774
```

Comment: Try `filter` version of `isalpha`

Comment: @jamylak -- Updated.  It's slower.

Comment: wow that's surprising, it must be better for larger inputs though

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
import re
my_list = [x for x in my_list if re.match("^[A-Za-z_-]*$", x)]
```

Comment: Where did you get this predefined character set?

Answer (score 0):

Sure, use the string builtin for digits, and test the existence of them.
We'll get a little fancy and just test for truthiness in the list comprehension; if it's returned anything there's digits in the string.

So:

```
out_list = []
for item in my_list:
    if not [ char for char in item if char in string.digits ]:
        out_list.append(item)
```

Answer (score 0):

And yet another slight variation:

```
>>> import re
>>> filter(re.compile('(?i)[a-z]').match, my_list)
['hello', 'hi']
```

And put the characters that are valid in your re (such as spaces/punctuation/other)